# How to send output from component via router-outlet to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, components, output

I need to emit a string when
**Parent page**

```
<div class="container-fluid fluidy">
     <router-outlet (currentpage)="componentAdded($event)"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Parentpage.ts**

```
  componentAdded(stringer){
    console.log(stringer);
    this.currentpage = stringer;
  }
```

**Child page**

```
  @Output() currentpage = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentpage.emit('profile');
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a component is launching inside router-outlet, its no more a child component of component having router-outlet. hence normally having output on router-outlet tag will not work. Instead you can do something like

**Parent component html**

```
<router-outlet (activate)="componentActivated($event)" (deactivate)="componentDeactivated($event)"></router-outlet>
```

Parent component ts

```
componentAddedSubscription: Subscritption;
componentActivated(component) {
    if(component instanceof ChildComponent) {
         this.componentAddedSubscription = component.currentpage.subscribe(res=>{
              //your logic
         });   
    }
}

componentDeactivated(component) {
   if(component instanceof ChildComponent) {
         if(this.componentAddedSubscription?.unsubscribe) {
             this.componentAddedSubscription.unsubscribe();
         }
   }
}
```